# Can't create new or open Netbeans projects in Ubuntu 14

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, project

When to try to create a project in Netbeans, it freezes up after clicking Finish. All my buttons are greyed out, and I have to close the dialogue. I would attach a picture to show, but Im missing a few rep points.

After I close this dialogue, I just see the blank netbeans screen with no projects visible in my projects sidebar.

If I try to Open Project and navigate to where I saved it, I can select the project and click the Open Project button, but I return to the screen shown above, with no projects in the projects navigator in the sidebar.

Here is what I have already tried:

- Reinstall netbeans
- Remove openjdk and install oracle's java
- Deleting the nbproject folder inside my project

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of NetBeans do you have?

Comment: I have Netbeans 7.0.1

Comment: Please try again with NB 8.0

Comment: Looks like the same issue as http://askubuntu.com/questions/484654/problem-with-netbeans-7-0-1-on-ubuntu-14-04 - the fix is to downgrade your libnb-javaparser-java package.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experience with Netbeans after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.  My eventual solution was to download and install the Netbeans 8 for linux from the Oracle site, complete with its JDK.  I installed that.  During the installation was asked if I wanted to import the settings from the previous version of Netbeans, I answered NO to that and then pulled my existing projects in manually,  They are all working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install netbeans from https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.0.1/ install and don't import earlier settings. Everything works good.

Comment: i did the same but nothing happens